# F1 Visa Internship Question

Tags: career-path

Can I do an internship during my first semester of college in a state other than the one where my university is located?

Comment: Best ask the university...

Comment: Please check this with the international students office of your university. For what I understand, F-1 holder can have on-campus part time job during the semester.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you generally cannot. F-1 visas holders are allowed to hold part-time (up to 20 hours/week) on-campus jobs during all semesters enrolled (though I'm told that some positions don't count as on-campus, despite physically taking place on-campus). Authorization for off-campus work can only be granted [after the first academic year](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment).

As scaaahu suggests, you should ask the international office at your university about your specific situation. They should be able to advise you also about potential exceptions to what I wrote above, e.g. unpaid internships.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for CPT (Curricular Practical Training) after completing your first year, sponsored by your school/department. You will need to receive credit for it. This is different from OPT (Optional Practical Training) where you can apply within the first year after your graduation.

Comment: Can you really apply for CPT during the first year of studies though? See the link in my answer, which seems to say no. Also, there is both pre- and post-completion OPT, so you don't necessarily need to wait to graduation for OPT.

Comment: you're correct that you're not eligible for the first year. I will revise my answer. Thanks for catching that.